Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered
I have report viewer working perfectly fine but, there is a hidden div with the following message

The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file.  Add <add verb="" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

This is the web.config of the project
<buildProviders>
  <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
  </buildProviders>
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
  <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
</assemblies>


<handlers>
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
</handlers>

<httpHandlers>
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" validate="false" />
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

The assembly is registered on the page with
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

These are the things that i've done to try and fix the issue

Updated the webforms to latest and changed version where required
Removed the older version handlers
switched iss to classic mode

Above approaches doesn't stop the issue and switching to classic mode also gives 500 Internal Server Error .
Can someone help me fix this issue.

That's the expected behaviour. The hidden messages will only be made visible if there is a problem with the report viewer.
For example, I see two hidden divs:
<div id="rv_HttpHandlerMissingErrorMessage" style="border-color:Red;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;padding:10px;display:none;overflow:auto;font-size:.85em;">
    <h2>Report Viewer Configuration Error</h2>
    <p>The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application&#39;s web.config file.
    Add &lt;add verb=&quot;*&quot; path=&quot;Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd&quot; type = &quot;Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91&quot; /&gt; to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add &lt;add name=&quot;ReportViewerWebControlHandler&quot; preCondition=&quot;integratedMode&quot; verb=&quot;*&quot; path=&quot;Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd&quot; type=&quot;Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91&quot; /&gt; to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.</p>
</div>
<div id="rv_BrowserNotSupportedErrorMessage" style="border-color:Red;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;padding:10px;display:none;overflow:auto;font-size:.85em;">
    <h2>Browser not supported</h2>
    <p>Report Viewer requires a standards compliant browser. Users of Internet Explorer 8 and earlier should switch to a modern browser, or if already using a modern browser target standards mode by adding the &lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;X-UA-Compatible&quot; content=&quot;IE=edge&quot; &gt; header tag to the host page.</p>
</div>

neither of which appear in the page.
So unless your report viewer isn't actually showing, then there's no "issue" to fix. :)

is there a way we can remove these snippets from the responses?

You'd have to write your own custom control - for example, MvcReportViewer. But it's not clear why you think you need to remove these hidden elements, which are never visible to the user?

Application security team wants me to remove it as it is giving verbose error messages

Then they don't understand what they're talking about. If you can't get them to see sense, then you'll have to write your own report viewer control.
